# APK not built properly

Tags: android

I tried installing my android application on an Android-powered phone. And I know that, as the APK is being installed in the device, automatically it creates a folder of that application. But my application doesn't create a folder, anyone who has an idea on how I resolve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you by folder mean launcer icon to start the app from...

Have you added

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

to one of your activities in the manifest file?